# Swift; Multiple paths in navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue

I'm building an iOS app, using storyboards. I have a navigation controller and multiple view controllers embedded in it. See the image below:

[image: Overview on storyboard]

When I try to take the red path, I get an error when when view controller 3 is appearing:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    navigationController!.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

it gives me:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

so it seems like the navigation controller isn't available when I navigate through the red path. All other path to view controller 4 works as they are suppose to. All segues are `show (e.g. Push)`

Am I making some obvious mistake here?

Comment: Is your navigationController connected with an IBOutlet?

Comment: No outlets are connected to the navigation controller.

Comment: When are you calling the segue? On a button push?

Comment: from didSelectRowAtIndexPath.. `if tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) is SimpleStoreTableViewCell {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("Show Store View", sender: indexPath.row)
        }`

Comment: If you comment out the setNavigationBarHidden out, does the segue still work?

Comment: Then it crashes next time i wan't to use the navigation controller.. in view didAppear in view controller 3: `navigationController!.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false`, if I commect those out as well, the segue works. But I need to have the navigation controller further on from view controller 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with the segue type (I put it to peprecated segues: `Push` and back to `Show (e.g. Push)`) it worked out. I think a clean would have solved the problem too!

It is perfectly fine to have multiple paths reaching the same points in a navigation controller.